# Yocto Build fails to at `go get` command within Bitbake Recipe for InfluxDB

Tags: go, yocto, influxdb

I have cloned [this meta-influx fork](https://github.com/kraj/meta-influx/tree/kraj/develop) and added to my layers folder in my Yocto directory.

I have also added it to my `bblayers.conf` and tried baking it using:

```
bitbake -k github.com-influxdata-influxdb
```

which provides me the following error logs:

```
ERROR: github.com-influxdata-influxdb-1.0-r0 do_configure: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/github.com-influxdata-influxdb/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_configure.29201)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/github.com-influxdata-influxdb/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_configure.29201
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing python function sysroot_cleansstate
| DEBUG: Python function sysroot_cleansstate finished
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_configure
| /opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/github.com-influxdata-influxdb/1.0-r0/temp/run.do_configure.29201: line 120: /opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/github.com-influxdata-influxdb/1.0-r0/github.com-influxdata-influxdb-1.0/bin/gdm: No such file or directory
| WARNING: /opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/github.com-influxdata-influxdb/1.0-r0/temp/run.do_configure.29201:1 exit 1 from 'go get github.com/sparrc/gdm'
| ERROR: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/github.com-influxdata-influxdb/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_configure.29201)
ERROR: Task 392 (/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/sources/poky/../meta-influx/recipes-go/go/github.com-influxdata-influxdb.bb, do_configure) failed with exit code '1'
```

The code says fails at the `go get sparrc gdm` within the [recipe file for influxdb](https://github.com/kraj/meta-influx/blob/kraj/develop/recipes-go/go/github.com-influxdata-influxdb.bb#L17).

On the host machine I do not have `golang` installed. Is it necessary to have go on the build machine?

(Target board is a PhyTec Mira Board with i.MX6 processor on it)

How do I resolve this issue? I am using `krogoth` branch (because the board providers have documentation in accordance with the branch)

#### Update

Even without `golang` being installed on the machine, the `gdm` is installed in my `/home/<user>/` folder under the directory `go` which has the `src/ bin/` folders. I still can't figure out how to download it to the appropriate `${B}` variable in the recipe mentioned above

Comment: It is necessary to have `golang` installed in the host machine and as you have not installed it , that's why you are getting the error while getting the repo using `go get`

Comment: who us the exact log

Comment: @HamzaAnis Hi i just found out that the `gdm` package was in fact downloaded in my `/home/<user>/` folder without `golang` installed on the machine. Is there anyway I could change the path of the download to `${B}` variable correctly in the recipe?

Comment: Install go in the user where you are running the bakefile and update the environment variables accordingly.